# rEFIt menu problem

Tags: 13.10, mac

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Macbook retina (Mid 2012) with USB.

On the installation type, I chose "Install Ubuntu along with MAC OS X" instead of "something else".

However, after installation, there're 3 options for me to choose on the rEFIt menu:

1. EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
2. EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
3. EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

I can still boot into Ubuntu by choosing one of them.

How can I fix this to make it shows just one Ubuntu logo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing rEFIt with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) fixed the problem.

Comment: worked like a gem :)